# App crashes when I try to convert HTML string to NSAttributedString - "NSInternalInconsistencyException"

Tags: html, ios, swift, crash, nsattributedstring

App crashes when I try to convert HTML string to NSAttributedString and assign it to a textView.

```
@IBOutlet weak var standingBillerNoteTextView: UITextView!

self.standingBillerNoteTextView.attributedText = isFlexSip ? paymentVM.flexSipPaymentNotes.htmlToAttributedString: paymentVM.sipSINotes.htmlToAttributedString
```

I am using below code for conversion -

```
extension String {
    
    var htmlToAtrributtedString: NSAttributedString? {
        guard let data = data(using: .utf8) else { return NSAttributedString() }
        do { 
            //**Crash is in below line**
            return try NSAttributedString(data: data, options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html, .characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue], documentAttributes: nil)
        } catch {
            debugPrint(error.localizedDescription)
            return nil
        }
        
    }
}
```

PFB the crash report -

```
# Crashlytics - Stack trace
# Platform: apple
# Date: Fri Dec 08 2023 20:45:06 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException
0  CoreFoundation                 0xed5e0 __exceptionPreprocess
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x2bc00 objc_exception_throw
2  Foundation                     0x6bc4d4 -[NSMutableDictionary(NSMutableDictionary) initWithContentsOfFile:]
3  UIKitCore                      0x297f80 (Missing UUID 948b271ad49d3b3fac082223908f51ab)
4  CoreFoundation                 0x361dc __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__
5  CoreFoundation                 0x34be4 __CFRunLoopDoObservers
6  CoreFoundation                 0x33e64 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
7  UIFoundation                   0xdace8 -[NSHTMLReader _loadUsingWebKit]
8  UIFoundation                   0xdb898 -[NSHTMLReader attributedString]
9  UIFoundation                   0x84128 _NSReadAttributedStringFromURLOrDataCommon
10 UIFoundation                   0x7f2b8 _NSReadAttributedStringFromURLOrData
11 UIFoundation                   0x7f130 -[NSAttributedString(NSAttributedStringUIFoundationAdditions) initWithData:options:documentAttributes:error:]
12 MyProject                      0x3bbbb0 @nonobjc NSAttributedString.init(data:options:documentAttributes:) (<compiler-generated>)
13 MyProject                      0x3bb6ec NSAttributedString.init(data:options:documentAttributes:) (<compiler-generated>)
14 MyProject                      0x3bb3dc String.htmlToAttributedString.getter + 96 (StringExtension.swift:96)
15 MyProject                      0x52e538 TransactionPaymentTableViewCell.setUpNotes() + 240 (TransactionPaymentTableViewCell.swift:240)
16 MyProject                      0x52b670 TransactionPaymentTableViewCell.configureCell(type:folioNumber:cellViewModel:frequencyType:schemeType:contactMissing:considering:dynamicDataVM:) + 135 (TransactionPaymentTableViewCell.swift:135)
17 MyProject                      0x63835c SIPSchemeViewController.tableView(_:cellForRowAt:) + 531 (SIPSchemeViewController.swift:531)
18 MyProject                      0x641a98 @objc SIPSchemeViewController.tableView(_:cellForRowAt:) (<compiler-generated>)
19 UIKitCore                      0x28a08c (Missing UUID 948b271ad49d3b3fac082223908f51ab)
20 UIKitCore                      0x289ac4 (Missing UUID 948b271ad49d3b3fac082223908f51ab)
21 UIKitCore                      0x288010 (Missing UUID 948b271ad49d3b3fac082223908f51ab)
22 UIKitCore                      0x287af8 (Missing UUID 948b271ad49d3b3fac082223908f51ab)
23 UIKitCore                      0x331d8 (Missing UUID 948b271ad49d3b3fac082223908f51ab)
24 QuartzCore                     0x67780 (Missing UUID 0fb9e837c0aa3977a0be28ba0f207a50)
25 QuartzCore                     0x67308 (Missing UUID 0fb9e837c0aa3977a0be28ba0f207a50)
26 QuartzCore                     0x6d844 (Missing UUID 0fb9e837c0aa3977a0be28ba0f207a50)
27 QuartzCore                     0x66b34 (Missing UUID 0fb9e837c0aa3977a0be28ba0f207a50)
28 UIKitCore                      0xe53790 (Missing UUID 948b271ad49d3b3fac082223908f51ab)
29 UIKitCore                      0xe01a3c (Missing UUID 948b271ad49d3b3fac082223908f51ab)
30 UIKitCore                      0xe51620 (Missing UUID 948b271ad49d3b3fac082223908f51ab)
31 UIKitCore                      0xe51a88 (Missing UUID 948b271ad49d3b3fac082223908f51ab)
32 UIKitCore                      0x122adb4 (Missing UUID 948b271ad49d3b3fac082223908f51ab)
33 UIKitCore                      0xbe3ff4 (Missing UUID 948b271ad49d3b3fac082223908f51ab)
34 UIKitCore                      0x79ebbc (Missing UUID 948b271ad49d3b3fac082223908f51ab)
35 UIKitCore                      0x79eef0 (Missing UUID 948b271ad49d3b3fac082223908f51ab)
36 UIKitCore                      0x79e5fc (Missing UUID 948b271ad49d3b3fac082223908f51ab)
37 UIKitCore                      0x20dad0 (Missing UUID 948b271ad49d3b3fac082223908f51ab)
38 UIKitCore                      0xc86fdc (Missing UUID 948b271ad49d3b3fac082223908f51ab)
39 UIKitCore                      0x2d24cc (Missing UUID 948b271ad49d3b3fac082223908f51ab)
40 UIKitCore                      0x2cfce4 (Missing UUID 948b271ad49d3b3fac082223908f51ab)
41 UIKitCore                      0x2cf418 (Missing UUID 948b271ad49d3b3fac082223908f51ab)
42 UIKitCore                      0x2ceb60 (Missing UUID 948b271ad49d3b3fac082223908f51ab)
43 UIKitCore                      0x10052c (Missing UUID 948b271ad49d3b3fac082223908f51ab)
44 UIKitCore                      0xffa6c (Missing UUID 948b271ad49d3b3fac082223908f51ab)
45 UIKit                          0xa3b8 -[UIKeyboardSceneDelegateAccessibility setInputViews:animationStyle:]
46 UIKitCore                      0xff9b8 (Missing UUID 948b271ad49d3b3fac082223908f51ab)
47 UIKitCore                      0x136534 (Missing UUID 948b271ad49d3b3fac082223908f51ab)
48 UIKitCore                      0x8a96ec (Missing UUID 948b271ad49d3b3fac082223908f51ab)
49 UIKitCore                      0xc5a94c (Missing UUID 948b271ad49d3b3fac082223908f51ab)
50 libdispatch.dylib              0x4300 _dispatch_client_callout
51 libdispatch.dylib              0x77b8 _dispatch_continuation_pop
52 libdispatch.dylib              0x1b5c0 _dispatch_source_latch_and_call
53 libdispatch.dylib              0x1a190 _dispatch_source_invoke
54 libdispatch.dylib              0x128a8 _dispatch_main_queue_drain
55 libdispatch.dylib              0x125b0 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF
56 CoreFoundation                 0x379bc __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__
57 CoreFoundation                 0x346c8 __CFRunLoopRun
58 CoreFoundation                 0x33e18 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
59 GraphicsServices               0x35ec GSEventRunModal
60 UIKitCore                      0x22f350 (Missing UUID 948b271ad49d3b3fac082223908f51ab)
61 UIKitCore                      0x22e98c (Missing UUID 948b271ad49d3b3fac082223908f51ab)
62 MyProject                      0xfbf9ec main + 20 (AppDelegate.swift:20)
63 ???                            0x1d2d47d44 (Missing)
```

I have seen many posts in stackOverflow, Medium, Apple developer, etc but did not find any solution. It occurs only in some devices and very random. Please provide a solution. Thank you in advance.

Comment: On which line the crash occurs ? Why don’t you return nil if string can’t be converted to data ?

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue? Unrelated but you can avoid the `guard let` with `let data = Data(self.utf8)`.

Comment: @PtitXav Tried returning nil still the issue persists. The crash is in NSAttributed initializer.

Comment: @Larme It is rarely reproducible. It is not reproduced every time.

Comment: I guess then it's not specific to a particular value and that you can reproduce it from time to time. I'd suggest then a concurrency issue?

Comment: Do you have an example of html code you want to convert and that produce the crash ?

Comment: @Larme I have a question - Does NSAttributed's initializer run on a background thread?

Comment: No, read the doc: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsattributedstring/1524613-init but from your stack logs it's in main thread, no?